# Ios flutter app compiled with vscode not launching from device (launches from VSCode)

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code

I compile my flutter app with vscode.

It works when run it from vscode. But it crashes when I launch the compiled app by tapping app icon. This happens on debug configuration only (release works fine).

I am able to compile it with Xcode in debug mode and then it launches either from Xcode or by tapping icon.

What can I do here? I am not able to debug or see any message - the app just crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new flutter app and launched it from VSCode.

Then I stopped the app and launched by tapping app icon.

After that the following message appeared: "In iOS 14+, debug mode flutter apps can only be launched from Flutter tooling, IDEs with Flutter plugins or from Xcode. Alternatively build in profile or release modes to enable launching from the Home Screen".

So it is not a bug but a feature by design.